# Display Gibberish in VBA ListView (instead of Hebrew, Cyrillic, Arabic, Chinese, Japanese, Greek)

Tags: vba, excel, unicode

I've created a listview in VBA userform. The Listview showing the data inserted by user in 3 text boxes (after clicking on 'save' button). The user may insert text in hebrew, but in the listview the text is shown as Gibberish (see screenshot in the link below).

Please your help to show the Hebrew text in the listview.

The code of 'save' button:

```
Private Sub CB_Save_Click()
  Set Item = ListView2.ListItems.Add()
  counter = counter + 1
  Item.Text = counter
  Item.SubItems(1) = T_Problem.Value
  Item.SubItems(2) = T_ItemT.Value
  Item.SubItems(3) = T_ActionDesc.Value
End Sub
```

[image: screenshot of listview displaying Jibrish instead of Hebrew]

Comment: unfortunately due to VBA's lack of unicode support, you have to process hebrew character by character using `ChrW()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

1. Select the ListView in Developer Mode
2. Press <kbd>F4</kbd>
3. Press Fonts
4. Select Script > Hebrew
5. <kbd>Ok</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this (taken from [spreadsheet1.com](https://www.spreadsheet1.com/how-to-display-foreign-characters-in-vbe.html)), originally written to support Chinese but works all the same for Hebrew

> 1. Open Control Panel
> 2. Click Region
> 3. Click the Administrative tab
> 4. Click the Change system locale button Select which language to use when displaying text in programs, such as VBE, that do not support
>    Unicode. The setting will affect all user accounts on your computer.